# ARM Undefine Instruction

Tags: c, gcc, arm

Estoy compilando en el `IDE DS-5` un *embedded C* software para un producto de `NXP IMX6UL bare metal` que es un *ARM cortex A7*. No estoy usando ningún sistema operativo.

El asunto es que lo estoy usando el compilador de *AMR GCC 7.2.1 [arm-none-eabi]* con los siguientes flags:

> C Flags: -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o -g 
>   -Wall -mno-unaligned-access -MMD -MP -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -mapcs -std=gnu99
>
> ASM Flags: -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -g
>   -Wall -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -mapcs -std=gnu99
>
> Linker Flags: -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -g
>   -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -mapcs --spec=nosys.specs --specs= nano.specs -Xlinker --gc-sections -Xlinker -statics -Xlinker -z -Xlinker muldefs

El programa compila bien, 0 errors 0 warnings, pero al momento de usa cualquier function de *libgcc* o *lib*, functiones como *fopen* o *printf*, este da:

> undefined instructions error

Algunas funciones como el *malloc* no presentan el error anterior, estas simplemente devuelven `null`.

Mi suposición es que de alguna manera las librerias de *gcc* que se usan no estan compiladas para este tipo de *chipset* por lo que el *obj* contien instrucciones que el procesador no entiende. Aunque estas librerias fueron descargadas de la misma pagina de `NXP`.

Alguna idea de como resolver esto?

Aqui esta el codigo simplificado

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        FILE * file = NULL;

        file = fopen("D:\\Test.txt", "rb");
        if(file){
            printf("File opened");
            fclose(file);
        }else
            printf("Fail to open file");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Lo siento, la bola de cristal se me rompío el mes pasado. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo mínimo y completo de código que reproduzca el problema?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct __filestruct{
    uint32_t    offset;
    uint32_t    addr;
    uint32_t    size;
}file_struct_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    file_struct_t lut[]={
        {0x001C, 0x08003AB0, 0x1C8},
        {0x0A90, 0x080098B0, 0x400},
        {0x238C, 0x0800FC4B, 0x058},
        {0x38F4, 0x0801A7C5, 0xA0B8}
    };

    FILE * file = NULL;

    file = fopen("D:\\Test.txt", "rb");
    if(file){
        printf("File opened");
        fclose(file);
    }else
        printf("Fail to open file");

    return 0;
}

Comment: Por favor... edita la pregunta y añade el código ahí. Los comentarios son para comentar no para poner partes esenciales de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

No puedo probar el error de primera mano por falta de los materiales, pero puedo decirte que efectivamente es muy probable que muchas de las utilidades de libc dependan de la existencia de un sistema operativo.

La documentación de gcc te advierte que la bandera -ffreestanding (para compilar sin sistema operativo) implica que puede no existir la biblioteca estándar:

> -ffreestanding
>
> Assert that compilation targets a freestanding environment.
>   This implies -fno-builtin. A freestanding environment is one in which the
>   standard library may not exist, and program startup may not
>   necessarily be at main. The most obvious example is an OS kernel. This
>   is equivalent to -fno-hosted.

Ante mi falta de experiencia en estos casos, solo te puedo guiar a seguir buscando documentación sobre tu plataforma de programación en concreto. Quizas un lugar para empezar pueda ser la página sugerida por la propia documentación de GCC que habla de los estándares soportados en las diferentes implementaciones:

[Language Standards supported by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards)